# What is the difference between Tensorflow Hub vs Tensorflow Official Models?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Regarding Tensorflow models in Tensorflow Hub (https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow) vs models found on official Tensorflow Github Repository (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official):

- Does Tensorflow regularly maintain and update both of them?
- What are the biggest differences between them?
- What functionality does one have that the other doesn't?
- Do they have overlaps models (i.e Resnet, R-CNN)? Are there some models that are only exclusive to one of them?
- Are they installed differently? Why or why not?
- Are they deployed on differently? Why or why not?
- Is one more "official" than the other? Does one have more stable models?
- As a user of the model, what would be the biggest difference in experience while using them?

Thanks!

Comment: Found some information here: https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/03/introducing-model-garden-for-tensorflow-2.html. Would like more of an explanation though. Thanks!

Comment: We mostly expect users of TF Hub to treat models as blackboxes with clearly defined inputs and outputs. If a model meets your needs (eg. accuracy, speed, size, pre-training category), then use it! If you instead want to dig into the internal details of a model's structure, then you may be more interested in code-first resources, such as Model Garden or Keras applications. These often come with pre-trained checkpoints that can be loaded with the provided code.